# automatically expand a tree on loading the body

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Hi all Iam new to JSF technology how to automatically expand the tree on loading the page in by using rich:tree tag.

```
<rich:tree switchType="client"
value="#{Bean.deviceServiceTreeRoot}" var="item">
<rich:treeNode>
<h:commandLink value="#{item.name}"
action="#{Bean.getLink()}"
style="color:blue;text-decoration:none;"
title="#{item.Description}">
<f:param name="productIDs" value="#{item.ID}"></f:param>
</h:commandLink>
</rich:treeNode>
</rich:tree>
```

Now by using the above code i can display a tree structure.The above is present in one page After clicking on submit button it will redirect to another page In that page I need to have the tree in expanded mode How can I achieve that Is that possible?

Comment: [Click here](https://community.jboss.org/message/30212) to see the answer for the above question.

Comment: How about you copy/paste the answer into this question, and accept that answer.  Then the question here will be "complete".

Comment: I solved this issue, when I worked with ice:tree. I mean, it could help the same: you probably have to set some property in the tree model (like userObject.setExpanded(true); where userObject =  DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        IceUserObject userObject = new IceUserObject(node);

Answer (score 1):

```
<rich:treeNode expanded="#{true}">
```

has done the trick for me

Comment: what RF version are you using?

Comment: RF version 4.2.2.Final